# Which way of checking for Document ready() is better in jQuery from a performance point of view?

Tags: jquery

I've read [an article about 20 top jQuery tips](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/20-top-jquery-tips-tricks-for-jquery-programmers/) that uses the below code snippet:

```
//Use
$(function(){
    //document ready
});
```

is better than using the below code:

```
//Instead of
$(document).ready(function() {
    //document ready
});
```

I've always used the second code snippet. Is there any benefit on using the first one? Why is the second code snippet is better from performance perspective?

Comment: It's less code that the user must download and less bandwidth to use.

Comment: @CoDeaDDict it's not mentioning about performance issues! My question is about performance, not just difference between them in overall.

Comment: Note that that point from the "20 tips" article doesn't mention performance, doesn't say either option is "better", and in fact doesn't give any explanation at all. It simply calls it an "alternate" (presumably the author _meant_ "alternative"). The advantage to you the coder is that it is quicker to type.

Comment: some of the previous tips was about performance, and I thought this on is about performance as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't signification difference in terms of performance. The first version is shorthand of second one which means if you use first version jQuery's uses `ready` handler anyway.

First version is short, quickly typed while second one is more readable.

The article that you mentioned is about tips which gives you a tip that there exists shorthand version of `ready` handler, it doesn't bind you to always use first shorthand method, it is up to you which one you go with.

Comment: $(function(){ //document ready }); this code actually runs and never checks that DOM is ready. is that right? We use it without checking whether DOM is constructed or not, right?

Comment: No both are same, as said that is just shorthand version of second so it also runs when DOM is ready

Answer (score 2):

First one is short form of second one as **[@Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz)** Sir mentioned.

For more see:

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/
- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-document-ready-vs-function
- http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/ecaebf42a4fb3fae

Comment: The question in your first dot point is unrelated: it's comparing a jQuery function with a non-jQuery function.